# Instant app "speed bump" window. Is it possible to customize?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I need to create an instant app and I've seen sometimes a kind of splash screen appears before content is loaded. I have found no documentation related just that seems this screen is called **'Speed bump'**. It has the app's logo and name.  Is it possible to add extra information like one or two small statements to inform user what's happening? (Eg. Your XXXX is being prepared).

In case is possible, should it be modified by code (which class?) or by the Google console?